# Netmiko to login into 1000+ cisco router to check clock

Tags: python, automation, netmiko

I am using python + netmiko for network automation , We have 1000's of device to manage. I am using threading to perform the task faster but I always receive read timeout exceptions if thread reaches 250+ devices.

Comment: What is your question ? Have you tried limiting the number of threads to 200 ? Why is the read timing out ? Do you have a good network connection ? How are you handling the errors ?

Comment: Try to reduce concurrent connection count. If you are using AAA server, also pay your attention to concurrent connection to it. have a look at the `nornir` package which helps to deal with a lot of devices.